# Realm database integration with Eclipse Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, realm

I need to integrate Realm database in my eclipse JUNO(Android Development Tool). I used realm 0.81.1 version. I had include all library files in my android project lib folder and configured realm-0.81.1.jar in buildpath.when **"java.lang.IlleagaArgumentException:User is not part of the schema for this realmrun my project it throws error ".**

Here User is an class that extends `RealmObject`.
The User class code is given below:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String          name;
    private int             age;
    @Ignore
    private int             sessionId;
    // Standard getters & setters generated by your IDE…
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void   setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int    getAge() { return age; }
    public void   setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
    public int    getSessionId() { return sessionId; }
    public void   setSessionId(int dontPersist) { this.sessionId = sessionId; }
}
```

The error is produced when executing the following code:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);

realm.beginTransaction();
User user = realm.createObject(User.class);
user.setName("Jhon");
user.setAge(10);

realm.commitTransaction();
```

Please give me suggestion to work with Realm Database
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Eclipse you need to add the `@RealmClass` annotation manually as it doesn't support inherited annotations. So you model class must look like this:

```
@RealmClass
public class User extends RealmObject
{
  // ...
}
```

Try this and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I used @RealmClass annotation. but it also repeats same error

Comment: 'Annotation processing' -> 'Enable project specific settings' from project settings. Please check it and try.

Comment: In my project properties there is no annotation processing option under java compiler. what can i do?